# Mysql server is not getting started on Amazon ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, innodb, amazon-ami

I have installed mysql server on ec2 AMI. Suddenly stopped working mysql server and its not getting started.
Here is `mysql log` :

```
160629  4:28:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 3059 ...
160629  4:28:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160629  4:28:37 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html
160629  4:28:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160629  4:28:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160629  4:28:37 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160629  4:28:37 [ERROR] Aborting

160629  4:28:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160629 04:28:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file      /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Here are approach what I have tried yet:

1) Upgraded EC2 t2.micro to t2.medium.

2) Increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in my.cnf

3) Rename `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`

Please suggest what next step should I do to start mysql.

**Edit:**

`Sudo free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3954        149       3805          0          9         86
-/+ buffers/cache:         53       3901
```

**Edit:**

Is there only solution to uninstall mysql and re-install ?
If yes, then how can retain already created databases in mysql? Please Suggest.

Comment: I have upgraded server from t2.micro to t2.medium so it has 4GB ram and free memory is `3805`

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link which is  being given in your error logs.
It has  mentioned  certain steps to solve runtime exception .You can  cross check and proceed. If  nothing helped than you can opt for uninstallation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html

Comment: I have cross verified these steps seems everything fine.